# Call dynamic method from string

Tags: c#, dynamic, methods, reflection

I'm trying to call a method from a dynamic without knowing its name. I have difficulties to explain this in english so there's the code:

```
public void CallMethod(dynamic d, string n)
{
    // Here I want to call the method named n in the dynamic d
}
```

I want something like:`d.n()` but with *n* replaced by the string.

I want this :

```
Type thisType = this.GetType();
MethodInfo theMethod = thisType.GetMethod(TheCommandString);
theMethod.Invoke(this, userParameters);
```

but with **dynamic**.

If you need the context to help you: I'm make an application that's support "mods", you put DLLs in the mod folder and it loads it and execute it. It works with **dynamic** (I have a dictionnary like this : `Dictionnary<string, dynamic> instances;`). I want the application to get the methods name from the library (with `instances["topkek"].GetMethods();`, I've already made this method) but then call the method with the string it returns. I don't know if what I said mean something (I'm french :/ )...

I'm using VS 2013 Express with the .Net framework 4.5, if you need more information to help me ask me.

Comment: How will you know which method to call? You can use [`Type.GetMethods`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getmethods) on a 'normal' `Type` - not sure how it'll work with `dynamic`.

Comment: Your question is too broad and provides a very little detail. Please try to put in some effort and explain yourself.

Comment: The method is specified by the user, I want something like: "d.n()", ofc if the method doesn't exists it will crash. So this isn't possible with dynamic ?

Comment: Why not pass a delegate instead?

Comment: Look into reflection, here is a tutorial http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_reflection.htm

Comment: I made some modification to my post, I don't know if it's better

Comment: Ow, I just understood your comment Yuval, that's not stupid at all ! I'll try that :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can write your method as follows -

```
public void CallMethod(dynamic d, string n)
    {
        d.GetType().GetMethod(n).Invoke(d, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If all methods are void, this could work. Otherwise you need to change it a bit.

```
    public void CallMethod(string className, string methodName)
    {
        object dynamicObject;
        // Here I want to call the method named n in the dynamic d
        string objectClass = "yourNamespace.yourFolder." + className;
        Type objectType = Type.GetType(objectClass);
        if (objectType == null)
        {
            // Handle here unknown dynamic objects
        }
        else
        {
            // Call here the desired method
            dynamicObject = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            System.Reflection.MethodInfo method = objectType.GetMethod(methodName);
            if (method == null)
            {
                // Handle here unknown method for the known dynamic object
            }
            else
            {
                object[] parameters = new object[] { };   // No parameters
                method.Invoke(dynamicObject, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to create a new instance of my type, the instance is already the variable "d".

Comment: @SwagLordKnight Then it is even easier, you can skip the part to build the objectClass. Check [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.tryinvokemember(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: could you please name your parameters in a more descriptive way?

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair parameters is an array of object, to hold the parameters to be passed to the method. For example, if the method expect a string and an int, inside the brackets { } you need to add these 2 parameters: parameters = new object[] { str, number }  where str and number must be defined somewhere previously.

Comment: @BlasSoriano nono, I am talking about the signature of `CallMethod` ... :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair I agree. I should keep good practices instead of copying names from the original question. Thanks for pointing it; updated.

Answer (score 1):

I want to add another approach as solution:

In your case, the caller (developer of the mod) knows the method to call. Thus, this might helpful:

```
// In the main application:
public dynamic PerformMethodCall(dynamic obj, Func<dynamic, dynamic> method)
{
    return method(obj);
{


 // In a mod:
 mainProgram.PerformMethodCall(myDynamicObj, n => n.myDynamicMethod());

 // In another mod:
 mainProgram.PerformMethodCall(myDynamicObj, n => n.anotherMethod());
```

This is a further development of the idea of Yuval Itzchakov in his commentary. He had suggested using a delegate.