# Cannot apply indexing with [] with an expression of type "UILibs"

Tags: c#

I have this code in C# [ Program.cs ]:

```
UILibs mlib = new UILibs();
var selected = ""; // I have an Button_Click event that sets this to the button clicked name
private void createUILibraryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var func = mlib["UI_"+selected+"_MML"]; // trying to get the function
}
```

I get an error 'Cannot apply indexing with [] with an expression of type "UILibs"'

Here is the UILibs Class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UIC
{
   
    class UILibs
    {
        public string UI_DarkRound_MML() // Border size: 4
        {
            return @"
local firstUIMML = 'Hello, first UI test'
print(firstUIMML)
            ";
        }
    }
    
}
```

Im trying to index the UILibs class with "[]" to get the function ( Example: mlib["UI_DarkRound_MML"] )

Comment: C# is not a dynamic language like JavaScript.

Comment: You could use reflection: `typeof(UILibs).GetMethod("UI_"+selected+"_MML")`

Comment: Yes, you *can* use reflection, but I would suggest rethinking the design that relies on static method names, accessed dynamically, like this. A method that takes the name and looks up the value in a dictionary would be far better.

Comment: That said, reflection is the answer in the strictest sense, so...

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [Call dynamic method from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30288955/call-dynamic-method-from-string)

Comment: @madreflection Yes, that does answer the question, thank you.

Comment: That's good, but I still want to urge you to use a design that does not involve reflection. Reflection should be a last-resort option and there are better options, like a method that takes a parameter and uses that to look up values in a dictionary. Don't try to use dynamic-language features in a static languge if you can avoid it.

Comment: @madreflection okay, I'll take that to note. Thanks for the tip!